# recover pickled data: pickle data was truncated

Tags: python, struct, pickle, shelve

Normally,  the `shelve` data should be read and write by only one process at a time, but unfortunately it was simultaneously read and write by two processes, thus corrupted it. Is there any way to recover all data in it ? Currently I just get "`pickle data was truncated`" exception after reading a portion of the data?

Data and code here :https://drive.google.com/file/d/137nJFc1TvOge88EjzhnFX9bXg6vd0RYQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you should share the code and sample data in your question text or a platform that can be seen publicly. We need to request access to see them.

Comment: Okay but you were uploaded as a zip file format. I should not have to download, extract, and open it on my local machine. As I said before, the best way to ask this question is sharing your code and data publicly, maybe not all of them, but small partion of them at least.